# Can we override parent website's web.config?

Tags: asp.net, web, web-config, iis-7.5

I have a website and a sub website. Now I am facing problem that is my sub website's web.config file is inheriting parent website's web.config file.
 My parent website's web.config file has some `<configSections>` and my sub website does not need these `<configSections>`.
How can I do this ? I try to search net but find nothing helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can specify `allowOverride` in the parent web.config in a [location section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6x6shw7.aspx) to allow child web.config values to override the parent ones.

You can also set `inheritInChildApplications` to false so that your sections aren't automatically inherited into the child web.config.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, but there is a problem I can't change or modify parent web.config (there are some issues). can we do some in sub web.config to achieve our goal?

Comment: No, you can't. A work around might be to just add the unneeded config sections to your child web.config.