# IIS directoryBrowse only for a single directory

Tags: iis, directory, web-config

My app has some directories like root/foo/bar1 & root/foo/bar2. I want to enable directoryBrowse for the directory "foo". I put a web.config in the directory with the following code:

```
<configuration>  
    <system.webServer>
      <directoryBrowse enabled="true" showFlags="Date" />
    </system.webServer>  
</configuration>
```

But now it is active for all sub directories (bar1 & bar2). I can put a new web.config files in each sub directory to disable it but it will be nice if theres another solution without an extra file for each sub directory. Is it possible?

Comment: You can try to create a web.config in the folder you want to enable browsing to with this code `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
         <configuration>
                <system.webServer>
                    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
                </system.webServer>
        </configuration>` Theoretically this overrides main web.config

Comment: Thats the same code like my posted web.config or I am missing something? Just to make it clear: The directory browse is working. But I want it only for a single folder and not for all sub folders.

Comment: Maybe you need to allow web.config overriding https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9234492/can-we-override-parent-websites-web-config

Comment: I tried location and inheritInChildApplications without success :(

Comment: I have tried to use the location with the directoryBrowse  enabled to true, it works well on my side. I suggest you could check the foo,bar2 folder's web.config file to make sure there is no directoryBrowse  enabled to false setting.